# Trying to understand Trino and how it handles Time Zones

Tags: timezone, dbeaver, timestamp-with-timezone, trino

I'm observing strange behaviors when trying to convert timestamps between time zones in Trino. I believe it may be due to some conversions not behaving as expected. Perhaps someone can explain why `CAST(current_timestamp as timestamp)` observes the current time zone setting, but `current_timestamp` does not?

Example:

It is currently 4:08 PM Central Time (Chicago). When I run:

```sql
SET TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago';
SELECT 
  current_timezone() TZ
 ,current_timestamp TS
 ,CAST(current_timestamp as timestamp) CASTTS;
```

I get:
*TZ: America/Chicago

TS: 2022-07-26 16:08:06

CASTTS: 2022-07-26 16:08:06*

When I run:

```sql
SET TIME ZONE 'UTC';
SELECT 
  current_timezone() TZ
 ,current_timestamp TS
 ,CAST(current_timestamp as timestamp) CASTTS
```

I get:
*TZ: UTC

TS: 2022-07-26 16:09:37

CASTTS: 2022-07-26 21:09:37*

This is leading to additional issues when trying to convert a timestamp column from it's original timezone (UTC) to other timezones (Central/Eastern/etc)

Environment:

- I'm in Central Time Zone.
- Dbeaver 21.0.4
- Trino 391 jdbc driver
- Trino 380 (per `SELECT VERSION()`)
- Windows 10 Enterprise x64 21H2

Comment: I know it shouldn't matter, but is there any difference if you use `US/Central` instead?

Comment: ```current_timestamp``` returns a timestamp as the same time zone regardless. 
```cast(current_timestamp as timestamp)``` returns a timestamp as the selected timestamp
Does the timestamp data type include the zone, but disregard it when it's being cast? I would thing that casting a timestamp value to timestamp should retain the timezone information associated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dbeaver issue. Dbeaver shows all times in local time zone, even if specified otherwise. To fix it, go to Window > Preferences > Editors > Data Editor > Data Formats and then check the box that says 'Disable date/time formatting'.

Comment: Thank you. It's now showing me the requested timestamps in all conditions.